# Joomla not finding index.php after

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I had turned Use URL rewriting to ON 
Added some code in to the ht access file and this never worked.

I then turned off url rewriting and removed the code and now when I try to go to the website I am getting a 404 error.

I can still access /administration

the website is www2.daxtra.com

the page it should find is http://www2.daxtra.com/index.php/home

Does anyone have any ideas what has happened?

This was the code I added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you removed and correct code from the htaccess file and ensure you turned off the correct parameter on the Global Configuration?

Comment: I had added then removed this code:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` should be kept in there

Comment: Thanks kept it in and still getting the same error.

It is a .htaccess file and not htaccess.txt if that makes a difference

Comment: Is there a generic ht access file I can revert back to?

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/htaccess.txt Default Joomla .htacess if you need to revert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've done a small test.

To get what you want, you need to following:

1. **htaccess.txt** (you don't need a *.htaccess* file)
2. **Search Engine Friendly URLs** set to **On**
3. **Use URL rewriting** set to **Off**
4. You finally need to ensure that your Homepage menu items it set to a specific component such as an article or something else, not an Alias

This will ensure that you get `example.com/index.php/home`

Hope this helps